# PS1 prompt in fish (Friendly Interactive SHell) show git branch

Tags: fish

In `Bash` I have my `PS1` as

`PS1="\u@\h:\w\$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep -e '\* ' | sed 's/^..\(.*\)/{\1}/') \$ "`

Which will show my current `git branch` if I am in a git repo.

How do I set the `PS1` in `fish` so it will show me my current git branch?

Comment: I've found this function for resue:
https://coderwall.com/p/ycvusg/show-git-branch-name-in-fish-shell

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think this is the equivalent

```
function fish_prompt
    set -l git_branch (git branch 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/\* /s///p')
    echo -n (whoami)'@'(hostname)':'(prompt_pwd)'{'"$git_branch"'} $ '
end
```

Comment: [The carret `^` for STDERR redirect will be deprecated in future versions of fish](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#featureflags) (for future viewers). Currently it works by default.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58774049/5513492) for the edited version. `s/^/2>/`.

Answer (score 130):

@glenn already got the answer, but I've found a simpler way of showing the git prompt on fish.

From the terminal, in fish, type `fish_config`. This will open a browser window. Select the second tab `prompt` and under there select Classic + Git`.

This will show the commands required to show Git on the terminal prompt. Copy them to your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` or even simpler: click on "Use prompt".

How awesome is that?

Comment: You actually only need to click "Use prompt" - no copying required!

Comment: The commands do not show anymore. What is the current way of doing this?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat If you're using the debian package, you may experience [this issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1860#issuecomment-68012543). If you see a 404 File not found message in your terminal, create the missing link using: `ln -s /usr/share/javascript/jquery/jquery.js /usr/share/fish/tools/web_config/jquery.js` as root

Comment: To find the `fish_prompt` function that this answer winds up creating, I went to `~/.config/fish/functions/`. Note that this is exactly where fish reads the prompt function anyway, so it's now permanent. If you added a git feature (like show current branch) to your prompt, open a new tab and go to a git repo to verify the config is persisted.

Comment: it is now called `Classic + Vcs` as in Version Control System

Comment: Few things have changed now. Now they have "Classic + Git" section

Comment: Hmm... There is no "Classic + Git" in my latest fish. Also, clicking on one of the available prompts doesn't seem to show any commands.

Answer (score 7):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24582165/5513492) is using the [deprecated caret redirect to STDERR](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#featureflags). Use `2>` instead. Here is the edit

```sh
function fish_prompt
    #           Change is here:  vvv
    set -l git_branch (git branch 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/\* /s///p')
    #                            ^^^
    echo -n (whoami)'@'(hostname)':'(prompt_pwd)'{'"$git_branch"'} $ '
end
```

Here is a coloured prompt I have been using based on the one above:

```sh
function fish_prompt
    set_color normal
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581793/ps1-prompt-in-fish-friendly-interactive-shell-show-git-branch
    set -l git_branch (git branch 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/\* /s///p')
    echo -n (whoami)'@'(hostname)':'
    set_color $fish_color_cwd
    echo -n (prompt_pwd)
    set_color normal
    echo -n '{'
    set_color purple
    echo -n "$git_branch"
    set_color normal
    echo -n '}'
    echo -n ' $ '
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The builtin fish function `fish_vcs_prompt` generates the prompt for various version control systems, such as git.

Just integrate `(fish_vcs_prompt)` into your **fish** prompt:

`"\u@\h:\w(fish_vcs_prompt)\$"`

The git branch will be written in auto-added brackets with a space in front, for example:

> yoda@dagobah:~/git/myRepo (master)$